# How can a telegram bot save profile photo in a file?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

O have a telegram bot in C#, and I want to get the user's profile photo and save it to a special path.

Here is my code:

```
var photo = bot.GetUserProfilePhotosAsync( messageEventArgs .Message .From .Id ).Result ;
```

But the type of the result is `UserProfilePhotos`. How do I save this to a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UserProfilePhotos` is actually a collection of user photos. Its property `Photos` (of type `PhotoSize[][]`) contains user profile pictures (in up to 4 sizes each). You could save actual image associated with each `PhotoSize` either by its `FilePath` property or directly by `FileStream` property.

See this Telegram Bot API pages for details:

[UserProfilePhotos Class](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#userprofilephotos)

[PhotoSize Class](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#photosize)

Comment: The links was removed From git hub  can you give us the new ones?